# Cannot attach to x64 process using Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

I am having a problem attaching to the process w3wp.exe in  Visual Studio 2013. If I am attaching to w3wp.exe that has a x64 type, I'll get an error in the attached screenshot.

Basically, I have tried to attach a w3wp.exe process that has Managed type or x86 type and it works with no errors. But if I choose the x64 type, I will get the error in the attached screenshot.

Screenshot:
https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1hWRg-EjZLi7F-dIS0ytPko8y_h3xLL2QtZwjU8sBzOg/edit?usp=sharing

Would anyone have ideas? Thanks!

Details.
Visual Studio version: Version 12.0.21005.1 REL
Windows version:  Windows Server 2008 R2 (SP1)
IIS version: 7.5.7600.16835

Comment: It is a low-level networking error.  Only loosely associated with debugging a 64-bit process, Visual Studio is a 32-bit process so the remote debugger is always needed.  This is an environmental error, the first candidates on your list are always anti-malware and firewall.

Comment: thanks Passant for the response. we have good security in our server so I guess there is no suspicious malware there, and also our firewall is turned off. Also, I tried to use the x64 remote debugger "\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64\msvsmon.exe" and also the x86 too, but still I'm getting no luck.

Comment: Having "good security" is the cause of such problems.  Talk to the guy that administers this machine to get it turned off so you can do your job.  And avoid debugging your code on production machines.